# If $U$ has $0$ intersection with the nonnegative orthant, why does $U^\perp$ contain a strongly positive vector?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, reference-request

In my book, I'm doing an exercise that says I can use the fact that if $U$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$, and $U\cap\mathbb{R}_+^n=\{0\}$, where
$$
\mathbb{R}_+^n=\{(a_1,\dots,a_n)\mid a_i\geq 0\},
$$
then $U^\perp$ contains a strongly positive vector, that is, a vector whose coordinates are all positive.

I could do the exercise, but I don't like using a fact I can't prove. Is there a reference or proof of this fact available?

Comment: I asked a teacher for some help regarding the question, his suggestion was to separate $U$ with a hyperplane from $\mathbb{R}^n_+$. After that you must show that there exists a vector $a$ associated to the hyperplane (normal to the plane) such that $a>0$. He also mentioned it would be a consequence of Farkas' lemma, I think this presentation might [help](http://www.win.tue.nl/~rudi/farkas_handout.pdf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Julio Cáceres said, the [separation theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hahn%E2%80%93Banach_theorem#Hahn.E2.80.93Banach_separation_theorem) works here: since $U$ and $P=\{a\in\mathbb R^n: \forall i \ a_i>0\}$ are disjoint convex sets, with $P$ being open, there exists a linear functional $f:\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R$ such that $f\le 0$ on $U$ and $f>0$ on $P$. Since $U$ is a linear subspace, $f\le 0$ on $U$ is possible only if $f\equiv 0$ on $U$. Writing $f$ in terms of inner product,  $f(x)=\langle x,v\rangle$, we obtain the desired vector $v$.